# Como colocar dos tablas paralelas en Rmarkdown? library(kableExtra)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

estoy generando un script rmd para tratar de automatizar la generación de informes, ya lo tengo armado y con todas mis tablas listas, pero tengo un problema.

Necesito poner 2 tablas en forma paralela dentro del mismo  `R chunk` y no logro hacerlo, tambien probé poner cada tabla en un  `R chunk` separado

Mi codigo es este para las tablas :

```
fisiografia %>%
  select(1,5:9)%>%
  filter(Canton==n_canton)%>%
  gather(key = Pendiente, value= "Porcentaje (%)", 2:6)%>%
  select(2:3)%>%
   kbl(align = "c", digits = 2) %>% 
   kable_classic(full_width = F)%>%
  kable_styling(position = "float_left")
```

```
fisiografia %>%
  select(1:4)%>%
  filter(Canton==n_canton)%>%
  gather(key = Altitud, value= "Metros", 2:4)%>%
  select(2:3)%>%
   kbl(align = "c", digits = 0) %>% 
   kable_classic(full_width = F)%>%
  kable_styling(
    latex_options = "HOLD_position",
    position = "center")
```

He intentado con `HOLD_position, float_left, float_right` y sus multiples combinaciones no se porque una se coloca siempre abajo, dejo una imagen [image: Imagen]

Quiero que ambas aparezcan una alado de la otra, y como tienen diferentes dimensiones, no las he podido unir y generar una sola.

La salida del archivo es un `PDF` y estoy trabajando con `library(kableExtra)`

Agradecería alguna ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Rodrigo bienvenido, bienvenido. Una pregunta ¿el uso de `kableExtra` es imprescindible? ¿Lo estás usando para solucionar el problema de alinear las dos tablas o para otras cosas? Te pregunta porque con `knitr::kable()` tiene una solución muy simple, pero no sé si también funcionará con `kableExtra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googleando me encontré con [este atajo de Yiui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036680/align-multiple-tables-side-by-side), autor del paquete.

Si ponemos ambos data.frame en una lista y los pasamos a `knitr::kable()` ambas tablas van a salir a la par, es decir, alineadas horizontalmente.

#### Ejemplo mínimo:

```
knitr::kable(list(mtcars[1:4, 1:3], mtcars[5:9, 4:7]))
```

#### Copia del encabezado YAML

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
```

#### Copia de las opciones globales para chunks:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = "!t", out.extra = "")
```

#### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona, pero tiene algunos problemas y no sé si se pueden resolver fácilmente. De todos modos podría darte una pista para ir resolviendo tu problema.

1. Algunas funciones de `kableExtra` andan, pero otras dan un error de LaTeX. Si dependes de alguna de las que no están funcionando no sabría como resolverlo.
2. Algunos argumentos básicos de `kable()`, como `caption =`  no se resuelven bien. A `kable()` le puedes pasar un vector de captions, para poner la viñeta de más de una tabla, pero quedan alineados verticalmente. Se ve mal y no sirven para dar info adicional sobre la tabla.
3. La ubicación de la tabla en la página es como suele ser con LaTeX: va a poner la tabla donde mejor le parezca a su algoritmo. Y no hay `!H` que lo convenza de lo contrario. Es el precio a pagar por no tener que formatear y ubicar las tablas a mano, como en Word.

> Nota personal aparte: En mi experiencia usando `rmarkdown` con salida en LaTeX/pdf si no funciona bien desde el principio va a ser muy, pero muy difícil hacer que quede exactamente como te gusta. El problema es que las decisiones sobre formato se toman en LaTeX y eso es un mundo aparte. Mi "buena práctica" en estos casos es el conformismo: si es suficiente para que se entienda no me importa tanto que se vea bonito/bien diseñado/con buen uso del espacio. Cuando trato de editar el template de LaTex suelo arreglar un problema y crear dos o tres más en la misma operación. Comprendo que podrías tener otras prioridades.

Comment: Que tal? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, disculpa la demora en responder. Es lo que andaba buscando y me funciono con mis tablas, es cierto que no queda tan bonito como hubiera querido pero cumple su función y he aprendido algo nuevo. Te agradezco nuevamente.